# websphere deployment.xml composition unit is not found

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

While running the webservices in websphere, it's throwing this error:

```
[5/8/16 17:33:05:862 EDT]     FFDC Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.policyset.runtime.server.FileLocatorImpl.getAttachmentPath ProbeId:FFDC-2
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\config\cells\Node01Cell\applications\null.ear\deployments\deployment.xml (The system cannot find the path specified.)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:149)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:108)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:103)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:201)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.config.ConfigDocumentImpl.load(ConfigDocumentImpl.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.config.ConfigServiceImpl.getDocument(ConfigServiceImpl.java:182)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.config.ConfigServiceImpl.getDocumentObjects(ConfigServiceImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.config.ConfigServiceImpl.getDocumentObjects(ConfigServiceImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.policyset.runtime.server.FileLocatorImpl$2.run(FileLocatorImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.policyset.runtime.server.FileLocatorImpl$2.run(FileLocatorImpl.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.policyset.runtime.server.FileLocatorImpl.getApplicationAttachment(FileLocatorImpl.java:173)
    at com.ibm.ws.policyset.runtime.server.FileLocatorImpl.getAttachmentPath(FileLocatorImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.policyset.runtime.PolicySetUtil.getAttachmentPath(PolicySetUtil.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.policyset.runtime.PolicySetUtil.getClientAttachments(PolicySetUtil.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2PolicySetConfigurator.getPolicySetAttachments(WASAxis2PolicySetConfigurator.java:437)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2PolicySetConfigurator.associatePolicySets(WASAxis2PolicySetConfigurator.java:319)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.client.WSClientConfigurationFactory.completeAxis2Configuration(WSClientConfigurationFactory.java:459)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:223)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.updateEndpointDescription(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:534)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.updateEndpoint(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.updateEndpoint(DescriptionFactory.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.getPort(ServiceDelegate.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.getPort(ServiceDelegate.java:513)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99)
```

Can you any one suggest what would be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If couldnt find the cause, you can try to clear the WAS temp and wstemp dir, and reinstall your app. (it helped us in some cases..)

Stop the appserver first, then delete everything under temp/, and wstemp/, (at your install probably: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\temp*  and C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\wstemp* ), then uninstall-install the app on adminconsole.

You could also check if you have the latest fixpack, they fixed some issue like this..

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM94858